# Redirect page with jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have the following html code:

```
    <form method="post" name="b" >
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Field A</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='field[0][a]' id='field[0][a]'></td>
        <td>Field B</td>
        <td><textarea name='field[0][b]' id='field[0][b]'></textarea></td>
        <td><button>remove</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
<button id="mybutton">add form</button>

<div align="center">
<p><button onClick="dadosFormularios()" value="Registar" name="registar">Registo</button></p>
</div>
</form>
```

as you can see there's a button that when i click call the function "dadosFormularios()";

```
  function dadosFormularios(){

            var dadosFormulario={};
            var iterador=countForms;
            var i=0;

            while(i<iterador){

            dadosFormulario[i]={};
            dadosFormulario[i]['a']=$('#field\\['+i +'\\]\\[a\\]').val();
            dadosFormulario[i]['b']=$('#field\\['+i +'\\]\\[b\\]').val();   
            alert(dadosFormulario[i]['a']);
            alert(dadosFormulario[i]['b']); 
                i++;
            }

//i want to redirect here


    }
```

Now what i'm looking for is to use at the end of the above function something that redirects me to a php page (created by me) and receive there the array to treat the data he contains.
I searched and found things like "window.location = "http://www.google.com";" and other similars but nothing is working here. So if i can't redirect the page without clicking in a button i can't even think about passing vars with the redirection.

A little help please. Thank you!

Comment: It seems you're iterating an object as an array...I'd suggest you use `for...in` which is designed for objects.

Comment: ok, thank you, i will check your suggestion :P

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery to redirect, just javascript

```
window.location.href="page.html";
```

Comment: done, it was because a <form> tag i had in a wrong place i guess, it's working now the redirection, thanks :P

Answer (score 0):

Try `document.location = your-url-here;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you might want to do something like this:

```
var qstring = '';
var tmp_qstring = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < dadosFormulario.length; i++ )
{
       tmp_qstring[i] = 'a' + i + '=' + dadosFormulario[i]['a'] + '&' + 'b' + i + '=' + dadosFormulario[i]['b'];

}

qstring = tmp_qstring.join('&');

window.location = 'page.php?' + qstring;
```

basically this puts all the data into a query string then tacks it onto the end of your url, which you can then access via your php script with $_GET. it will be something like

```
page.php?a1=val&b1=val&a2=val&b2=val...
```

I think this is what you mean....

Comment: yes, it's something like that, the problem is that i can't redirect the page and don't know why. I tried window.location and the other sugestions given here and can't make one of them works :/

Comment: redirection solved :P
i will try know your suggestion to redirect with the content. It was to be with GET? Can't it be with POST?

Comment: Doug Johnson i guess the loop is not working, when the page is redirect nothing comes with "page.php?".
I inserted an alert within the cycle and he doesn't appear.

Comment: it's the method length() it returns "undefined"

Comment: it gives me a error on the concatenation.

it says on console:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined